# how to rename files in directorys using unix?

Tags: bash

How can I rename file with in subdirectories?

I have this sample:

```
001a
    abc001.tif
    abc002.tif
    abc003.tif
002a
    abcd001.tif
    abcd002.tif
    abcd003.tif
```

I want to rename each file in all subdirectories 001 - 00 x and not rename the directory itself. I want to rename the files sequentially starting with `0001` each folder of images start with 1.

This command, when I run it only works on the main folder and not the sub folders. What do I need to change to get it to run recursively on each subdirectory and have each dir start with 1.

```
for file in $path/*.tif; do
       mv -v "${file}" "$path/$(printf "%04d" ${num}).tif"
       num=$(( ${num} + 1 ))
done
```

The operating system that i am using is OSX

I a looking to drop abc form the the file name. This is just an example. Not every file will start with abc.

I tryed this, it renames but dose not start at one in each sub dir.
What can i change to get it to start at one?

```
num=0
for file in */*.tif; do
    echo mv -v "${file}" "$(printf "%04d\n" $num).tif"
    (( num++ ))
done

What can I change in the script to not have it move the files out of the orignial directory
```

Comment: Please would you provide an example [in your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/678130/edit) of how you want to rename them.

Comment: I want to rename the files sequencly starting with 0001

Comment: Is `002a/abcd001.tif` supposed to become `002a/0001.tif` or `002a/0004.tif`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and i) tell us what operating system you are using. Is it really UNIX? Or did you mean Linux? Either way, what UNIX and what Linux? The tools you have available will depend on that. ii) Show us what names you have now and what names you want to change to because this isn't clear. Ideally, show us the output of `tree` in the relevant directory. iii) your files are already named sequentially, so what should the new names be? Do you just want to remove `abc`?

Comment: [My code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/678282/100397) doesn't start at 1 in each directory BECAUSE YOU DIDNT STATE THAT IN YOUR QUESTION. You said "_I want to rename the files sequentially starting with 0001, removing the abc part and moving them out of the subdirectories._" which is what this code does.

Answer (score 0):

If you're got the perl-based `rename` tool installed, which is sometimes known as `prename`, you can do this in one line, like this

```
rename -n 's|^.*|sprintf "%04d.tif", ++$a|e' */*.tif
```

As written it will only tell you what it would have done. When you're happy, remove the `-n` to run silently, or replace it with `-v` to see what's happening.

If you don't have this tool you can write a loop very similar to yours,

```
num=0
for file in */*.tif; do
    echo mv -v "${file}" "$(printf "%04d\n" $num).tif"
    (( num++ ))
done
```

Remove `echo` when you're confident it will do what you want

Comment: I always recommend using `mv -i` or `-n` with any sort of bulk/automated move/rename operation, to avoid data loss if there's an unexpected name conflict.

Comment: If it's being run interactively from the terminal it'll stop and prompt if necessary. When I'm writing hard scripts I write defensively and programmatically check before using `mv -f`

Comment: `rename` will stop/prompt if necessary, but by default `mv` will just silently delete the original file if there's a conflict.

Comment: @GordonDavisson oh, yes, ok

Comment: Also is it posable to add an exclusion for file that have something in the filename when renaming. Or if file are in a direcory add do mot rename

Comment: There is no `rename` or `prename` on OS X (by default at least) so I'd go for the loop instead.

Comment: @Henno there isn't one by default on lots of systems. But if you have it, it's great

Comment: I wish Apple would provide a sanctioned repository to install utilities like this from using the command line… It would help many Unix minded users like myself…